# Chrome driver is not working in Lambda Function using Java-Maven

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I want to run my existing maven java code using lambda function.

I have created Deployment Package for Java 8 using maven eclipse. Now I want to open headless chrome using lambda. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

I am using

1. Java 8
2. Chrome 87 -> WebdriverManager (maven dependency)
3. Selenium 3.14.0

My Code

```
naws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

@Override
public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

    //context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
    WebDriver driver;
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            
    //AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
            
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().cachePath("/tmp").setup(); //create folder
        
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless"); // headless chrome driver
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
       
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    System.out.println("Google open in browser");
    driver.close();
    //return true;
            
    // TODO: implement your handler
    return "Hello from Lambda!";

}
}
```

ERROR

```
[1610702864.435][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)

unknown error: cannot find Chrome binaryBuild info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'System info: host: '169.254.98.77', ip: '169.254.98.77', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.203-112.332.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_201'Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriverremote stacktrace: #0 0x55a79c4e9e79 <unknown>: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverExceptionorg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binaryBuild info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'System info: host: '169.254.98.77', ip: '169.254.98.77', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.203-112.332.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_201'Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriverremote stacktrace: #0 0x55a79c4e9e79 <unknown> 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)  
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) 
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) 
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)  
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) 
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) 
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) 
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219) 
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)  
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181) 
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168) 
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157) 
at example.Hello.handleRequest(Hello.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Maven dependancies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>shade</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>


<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<formats>
<format>zip</format>
</formats>
</configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
<version>1.11.256</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
<artifactId>javase</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.30</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>2.41.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Have a look here to [how to indent your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300124/13903942)

Comment: @rutvik did you solve this eventually?